# Finding permutations efficiently

Tags: python, combinatorics

I have the following:

1. A set of `K` time-series in a numpy array with dimensions  `T x K`.
2. A set of `P` permuted approximation of them in a numpy array with dimensions `P times T`.

I need a dictionary that tells me which is the most probable permutation. For that I've created the following function, but I would like to know if can be done in a more efficient way and with less code to do this.

```
def find_permutation(true, permuted):
    """
    Finds the most probable permutation of true time series in between permuted time series
    :param true: true ordered time series of shape T times X
    :param permuted: Permuted time series of shape P times T. P > K
    :return: A dict containing {true idx: permuted idx}
    """
    N = true.shape[1]
    max_comps = permuted.shape[0]

    permutation_dict = {}
    used_comps = []

    corr_matrix = np.zeros((N, max_comps))

    # Find correlations
    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(max_comps):
            corr_matrix[i, j] = np.corrcoef(true[:, i], permuted[j, :])[0, 1]

    # Find best order
    per_matrix = np.argsort(-np.abs(corr_matrix), axis=1)
    for i in range(N):
        for j in per_matrix[i, :]:
            if j in used_comps:
                continue
            else:
                permutation_dict[i] = j
                used_comps.append(j)
                break

    return permutation_dict

if __name__ == "__main__":

    import numpy as np

    a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4.])
    b = np.array([4, 8, 9, 12.])
    c = np.array([9, 5, 8, 9.])

    true = np.vstack([a, b, c]).transpose()
    permuted = np.vstack([b*0.2, c*0.5, a*0.7])

    print(find_permutation(true, permuted))
    # {0: 2, 1: 0, 2: 1}
```

Here a Cython version

```
# C imports first
cimport numpy as np

# other imports
import numpy as np
import cython

# Type declarations
DTYPE = np.float
ctypedef np.float_t DTYPE_t

@cython.boundscheck(False)  # Deactivate bounds checking
@cython.wraparound(False)   # Deactivate negative indexing.
def find_permutation(np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] true, np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] permuted):
    """
    Finds the most probable permutation of true time series in between permuted time series
    :param true: true ordered time series of shape T times X
    :param permuted: Permuted time series of shape P times T. P > K
    :return: A dict containing {true idx: permuted idx}
    """

    cdef unsigned int N = true.shape[1]
    cdef unsigned int max_comps = permuted.shape[0]

    cdef dict permutation_dict = {}
    cdef list used_comps = []

    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] corr_matrix
    corr_matrix = np.zeros((N, max_comps))

    cdef Py_ssize_t i
    cdef Py_ssize_t j

    # Find correlations
    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(max_comps):
            corr_matrix[i, j] = np.corrcoef(true[:, i], permuted[j, :])[0, 1]

    # Find best order
    cdef np.ndarray[long, ndim=2] per_matrix
    per_matrix = np.argsort(-np.abs(corr_matrix), axis=1)

    for i in range(N):
        for j in per_matrix[i, :]:
            if j in used_comps:
                continue
            else:
                permutation_dict[i] = j
                used_comps.append(j)
                break

    return permutation_dict
```

Any suggestion is more than welcome.

Comment: do you have some (dummy) sample data with which you call this?

Comment: Added in the python code part :)

Comment: The cython code as is will not work for me. There are some imports and typedefs missing. Can you include thos?

Comment: In your docstring you mention `P >K`, but in your example `P == K` and is every time series represented at least once? or better, is there a 1 in each row of `corr_matrix`

Comment: Added type definitions, and imports. I hope I didn't miss anything. The objective of the function is to find among `P` times series those that are more correlated with `K`. That is way only `K` are returned. In the ideal case, would be at least one 1 for each row, but can happen that two series in `permuted` are more similar to only one in `true`, that's prevented by tracking them using `used_comps`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Pythonic

I rewrote a few of the loops to prevent looping over the index. I also changed `used_comps` to a `set` which has `O(1)` containment checks. For smaller arrays this will not matter a lot, for larger ones this can make a difference.

I also moved the `permutation_dict` and `used_comps` definitions closer to the place they are used.

```
def find_permutation2(true, permuted):
    """
    Finds the most probable permutation of true time series in between permuted time series
    :param true: true ordered time series of shape T times X
    :param permuted: Permuted time series of shape P times T. P > K
    :return: A dict containing {true idx: permuted idx}
    """

    corr_matrix = np.zeros((true.shape[1], permuted.shape[0]))

    # Find correlations
    for i, column in enumerate(true.T):
        for j, row in enumerate(permuted):
            corr_matrix[i, j] = np.corrcoef(column, row)[0, 1]

    # Find best order
    per_matrix = np.argsort(-np.abs(corr_matrix), axis=1)

    permutation_dict = {}
    used_comps = set()
    for i, row in enumerate(per_matrix):
        for j in row:
            if j in used_comps:
                continue
            permutation_dict[i] = j
            used_comps.add(j)
            break

    return permutation_dict
```

## numba

You can use `numba`, which compiles the python to llvm. I'm no expert, but I got it to work with these settings.

```
m_jith = numba.jit(find_permutation2, looplift=False, forceobj=True)
m_jith(true, permuted)
```

## `np.setdiff1d`

You can use [`np.setdiff1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html). This will be slower for smaller arrays, but might be faster for larger arrays.

```
def find_permutation3(true, permuted):
    """
    Finds the most probable permutation of true time series in between permuted time series
    :param true: true ordered time series of shape T times X
    :param permuted: Permuted time series of shape P times T. P > K
    :return: A dict containing {true idx: permuted idx}
    """

    corr_matrix = np.zeros((true.shape[1], permuted.shape[0]))

    # Find correlations
    for i, column in enumerate(true.T):
        for j, row in enumerate(permuted):
            corr_matrix[i, j] = np.corrcoef(column, row)[0, 1]

    # Find best order
    per_matrix = np.argsort(-np.abs(corr_matrix))

    permutation_dict = {}
    used_comps = set()
    for i, row in enumerate(per_matrix):
        j = np.setdiff1d(row, used_comps, assume_unique=True)[0]
        permutation_dict[i] = j
        used_comps.add(j)

    return permutation_dict
```

## timings

All these things have very little effect on the speed of the algorithm

```
%timeit find_permutation(true, permuted)
```

> ```
> 950 µs ± 23.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
> ```

```
%timeit find_permutation2(true, permuted)
```

> ```
> 978 µs ± 55.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
> ```

```
%timeit find_permutation3(true, permuted)
```

> ```
> 1.05 ms ± 58.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
> ```

```
%timeit find_permutation_jit(true, permuted)
```

> ```
> 1.08 ms ± 139 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
> ```

```
%timeit find_permutation_cython(true, permuted)
```

> ```
> 1.06 ms ± 135 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
> ```

But this can change with a larger dataset.

This close timing is probably because the python is not the bottleneck, but the `numpy` operations, most likely the `corrcoef`, but you'll need to do some profiling to see whether this is true.